# Flutter Bloc pagination working correctly, but the entire ListView.builder is rebuilt instead of simply appending the new items

Tags: flutter, pagination, flutter-bloc

I am relatively new to flutter_bloc, so forgive me if this is a simple question. I have a ListView.builder that renders out a list from my API, and my goal is to paginate this list. I have accomplished that, but the problem is that when I add new items to the list from my bloc, the entire ListView is rebuilt and the page jumps back up to the first item in the list.

Here is my bloc: I think the problem is that I am emitting the "MemesBlocLoaded" state at the end again? Or is it something else?

```
  final ApiRepository apiRepository;
  int page = 0;
  MemesBlocBloc(this.apiRepository) : super(MemesBlocInitial()) {
    on<GetMemesList>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        emit(MemesBlocLoading());
        List memesList = await apiRepository.fetchMemes(page);
        emit(MemesBlocLoaded(memesList));
        page++;
        on<GetMore>((event, emit) async {
          emit(const MemesBlocLoadingMore(true));
          List memesListMore = await apiRepository.fetchMemes(page);
          memesList.addAll(memesListMore);
          emit(const MemesBlocLoadingMore(false));
          emit(MemesBlocLoaded(memesList));
          page++;
        });
      } on NetworkError {
        emit(const MemesBlocError("Failed to fetch data."));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Edited with the build method:

```
if (state is MemesBlocLoaded) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListView.builder(
                          primary: false,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: state.memes.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Stack(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                    child: Image.network(
                                      state.memes[index].url,
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      height: 400,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Positioned(
                                  right: 16,
                                  bottom: 16,
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.comment),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                      IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            Icons.save_alt_outlined,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )),
                                      IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            Icons.share,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )),
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.report_outlined),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('profile');
                                            },
                                            child: const CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 16,
                                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554151228-14d9def656e4?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=686&q=80'),
                                            )),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            );
                          }),
                      state.memes.length >= 1
                          ? state is MemesBlocLoadingMore
                              ? const Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                      color: Colors.black),
                                )
                              : Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.white),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        context
                                            .read<MemesBlocBloc>()
                                            .add(GetMore());
                                      },
                                      child: const Text('View more',
                                          style:
                                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
                                )
                          : const SizedBox()
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
```

Comment: "the entire ListView is rebuilt and the page jumps back up to the first item in" - if it jumps then the problem is in your `build` method - post it's code

Comment: I posted the code for my build method where I trigger the rebuild.

Comment: does it happen if you, just for testing, remove those `MemesBlocLoadingMore` widgets?

Comment: I removed those, and I extracted the "context
                                            .read<MemesBlocBloc>()
                                            .add(GetMore());" method into its own function outside of the build function and it is still happening, unfortunately,  although it's still fetching the data correctly.

Comment: ok so remove the outer `SingleChildScrollView`, you don't need it - normally `ListView.builder` can be rebuilt multiple times and it should never jump to the first item, remove `shrinkWrap: true` too

Comment: Oddly enough that worked for one click of the button, but the same issue persisted after. It is still jumping to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not late. You should be doing something like the below code

Please check the repository with the same functionality
https://github.com/IndrajeetS/flutter-animation

```
on<PostsLoadMoreEvent>((event, emit) async {
  if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
      scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
    isLoadMore = true;
    page++;
    final newPosts = await _postRepository.fetchPosts(page);

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // Appending/Combining Old List with new list
    // ---------------------------------------------
    emit(PostsLoadedState(
      posts: [...state.posts, ...newPosts],
    ));
  }
});
```